Jeju Island - Visa-free entry via direct flight but indirect exit allowed?
I am an Indian citizen. My travel plan is as follows:
Delhi->Singapore>Pudong->Jeju.
The return route is:
Jeju->Incheon Intl Airport->Singapore->Delhi
So, I am not stopping over in mainland Korea during entry to Jeju but doing so during the return. Is it possible to do so?
Also, the booking websites (makemystip, goibibo) mention that I need a transit visa for Delhi-Jeju. Why is it so?
